# How to make an item background visible on overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have a small dropdown selection inside overflow box. Problem is I cannot make links background fill full width. Just try to scroll:

```css
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner a {
    background: none #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.inner.block a {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>inline-block:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some link title in here.</a></div>
    <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some much longer link title in here.</a></div>
</div>
<p>block:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner block"><a href="#">Some link title in here.</a></div>
    <div class="inner block"><a href="#">Some much longer link title in here.</a></div>
</div>
```

Also on **[Playground](http://jsfiddle.net/jscohdL0/)**.

I can modify CSS and HTML any way, the container has `position: absolute`. Also, the background is an image repeating, not a solid color.

How to make the background behind the text to extend to the edge?

Comment: If you scroll right, you will see the background is not filled. In my case I see the content below. I am testing on Firefox.

Comment: Of course, to take full width and cover the content below it.

Comment: Do you want it to work for both the inline-block and the block section or is either ok?

Comment: That is what I tried, but had no success. I do not care if it is inline-block or block.

Comment: Is javascript allowed? Can't figure out pure css solution... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my example, links are clickabe in full width, and you can add repeateable background easly.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some link title in here.</a></div>
        <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some much longer link title in here.</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer a{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://nonessentials.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/dots-small-pattern.png);
    background-size:cover;
}

.background {
    background: none #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uco57f05/3/)

Comment: So you wrapped it in inline-block and that fixed it. I still have no idea why, but it works great. Thanks, think this will be very useful answer.

Comment: Yes, it's because <a> tag is inline by default. If you will change normal <a> behavior to block, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap the links in another div. If you need background images per link, attach them to inner div. If you need the whole bar clickable, flip the `<a>`'s and the `<div>`'s. Like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="background">
        <a href="#"><div class="inner">Some link title in here.</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="inner">Some much longer link title in here.</div></a>
    </div>
</div>

.background {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.background .inner {
    background: none #ccc;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uco57f05/2/)

Hope that takes everything you needed into account.

Comment: It won't work with my repeating image background. Plus, links won't be clickable at the end. I want links to take all available width. Also, if I want to add hover effect I would be in trouble.

Comment: @skobaljic let me think about that

Comment: @skobaljic that should do it now. Right?

Comment: Yes, now it is almost same as from Urbanski. Think this is a correct way to fix the issue. Even if wrapping divs is ok with html5, think Urbanski's answer looks a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Without using any wrapper:</strike>

```
.inner {
  width: 300px;
}
.inner a {
    background: none #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%; /*addition*/
}
```

With wrapper:

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.cover {
  background: none #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inner a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner.block a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>inline-block:</p>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some link title in here.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="inner"><a href="#">Some much longer link title in here.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>block:</p>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="inner block"><a href="#">Some link title in here.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="inner block"><a href="#">Some much longer link title in here.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not know the inner width. For example will this fit in 300 (currently outer is 720 and I still have scroll): `digital cameras - canon - canon - company tr-130s light weight geared with pan & tilt  - camera / camcorder tripod (350mm - 1060mm / 40'`. So, the inner width must be flexible.

Comment: What html should this styles fit in? What is `.cover` here?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could be the solution:

```
<p>inline-block:</p>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="table">
    <div class="inner"><a href="http://google.com">Some link title in here.</a></div>
    <div class="inner"><a href="http://yahoo.com">Some much longer link title in here.</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table {
    display:table;
}
.inner {
    display:table-row;
}
.inner a {
    background: none #ccc;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner a:hover {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jscohdL0/27/

So, wrapper div again, but with display:table property, and inner divs as table-rows... Clickable, hoverable™...

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow, great ideas from great people! Thanks mate!

Comment: Like the idea, but at the end I think you will also agree this would be an alternative to Urbanski's answer. Thanks again.